# what does this ghidra-generated pseudo c-code generate?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I'm playing around doing a few challenges of reverse engineering with ghidra.

I have analyzed a bin file, which should contain some information about a password.
When you run the file, you can give it some input, and it will check if it's the correct password.
Here is the pseudo-c code that is responsible for doing this (The comments are me):

```
  __isoc99_scanf(&DAT_00400a82,local_28); // input scanned from user
  __s2 = (char *)FUN_0040078d(0x14); // password retrieved from function
  iVar1 = strcmp(local_28,__s2); // comparing strings
  if (iVar1 == 0) { // if they are equal, do this
    FUN_00400978(&local_48);
  }
```

Ok, so i tried looking up the function `FUN_0040078d`:

```
void * FUN_0040078d(int param_1)

{
  int iVar1;
  time_t tVar2;
  void *pvVar3;
  int local_c;
  
  tVar2 = time((time_t *)0x0);
  DAT_00601074 = DAT_00601074 + 1;
  srand(DAT_00601074 + (int)tVar2 * param_1);
  pvVar3 = malloc((long)(param_1 + 1));
  if (pvVar3 != (void *)0x0) {
    local_c = 0;
    while (local_c < param_1) {
      iVar1 = rand();
      *(char *)((long)local_c + (long)pvVar3) = (char)(iVar1 % 0x5e) + '!';
      local_c = local_c + 1;
    }
    *(undefined *)((long)pvVar3 + (long)param_1) = 0;
    return pvVar3;
  }
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
  exit(1);
}
```

So theres a lot of information here. But overall, what I think happens is that an array of chars is constructed, by doing the operation:

```
(char)(iVar1 % 0x5e) + '!';
```

Which I have no idea what means (what does modulo on chars do? and does `+ '!'` ) just mean concatenate a "!".

Overall I'm haivng some issues reading this, and I'm wondering if it's possible to predict what this function would output for specific inputs. In this case the function is given `14` as input.

Maybe the use of the `rand()` means that it cannot be deconstructed?

Can anyone give a guess/tell me whatthis function would likely output for input 14?

Comment: Given that part of the calculation involves a random number I'd say it'd be difficult to predict the output. Sorry!

Comment: yes, that was my fear as well. But since i'm fairly new tot this i thoguht that there might be a way around. thx!

Comment: Modulo never works on `char` — a `char` value is promoted to `int` and then the modulo operation is applied to the `int` value.  But the code shown has `iVar1` as an `int` anyway.  The result of the modulo operation is in the range 0x00..0x5D; the cast to `char` is a no-op; the addition of `!` (ASCII 33, 0x21) leaves the value in the range 0x21..0x7E, which are all printable, graphic characters in ASCII and related code sets (including ISO 8859-1 and Unicode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your previous comment, here's a simplified version of your function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

long GLOBAL_COUNTER = 0;

typedef char undefined;

void * array_constructor(int size);

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    char* random_string = (char*)array_constructor(0x14);
    printf("%s", random_string);
    free(random_string);
}


void * array_constructor(int size)
{
    int random_value;
    //time_t cur_time;
    void *array;
    int counter;

    //cur_time = time(NULL);
    GLOBAL_COUNTER = GLOBAL_COUNTER + 1;
    srand(0);//srand(GLOBAL_COUNTER + (int)cur_time * param_1);
    array = malloc((long)(size + 1));//returns a void array of param_1 + 1 elements 
    if (array == NULL) 
      exit(1);
    
    counter = 0;
    while (counter < size) {
    random_value = rand();
    int char_value = (char)(random_value % 0x5e) + '!';//Range of possible values 33-127
    // This is due to the fact that random value can have any value given the seed
    // but its truncated to a modulo 0x5e so its new range is 0 - 0x5e(94 in dec) 
    // and you add the bang symbol at the end so 0 + 33 = 33 and 94 + 33 = 127 

    *(char *)((long)counter + (long)array) = char_value;    
    // this statement is the same as
    // array[counter] = char_value
    counter++;
    }
    *(undefined *)((long)array + (long)size) = 0; //it puts the \0 at the end of the string
    return array;
}
```

now the only problem that you had was with the undefined `typedef`. this code is a simplification of yours. but it works.

Answer (score 1):

you got to remember that every char is a character representation of an 8bit value. Thus every operator is valid within the realm of chars.

I made this example for you to understand it better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    char character = 'A'; // 65 in dec
    char bang = '!'; // 33 in dec


    printf("'A' in dec: %d\n", (int)character);
    printf("'!' in dec: %d\n", (int)bang);


    
    // now the modulo operator works the same in chars
    character = 'a';
    char new_value = (char)character%64;
    printf("a %% 64 : char_value: %c, int_value: %d\n", new_value, (int)new_value);
    
    // you got to remember that chars are just a coded 8bit value
    
    char at_symbol = '@'; // 64 in dec

    // now the modulo operator works the same in chars
    character = 'a';
    new_value = (char)character%at_symbol;
    printf("a %% @ : char_value: %c, int_value: %d\n", new_value, (int)new_value);


    // it works the same with every other operator 
    

    
    int value1 = 300; //this is your random value

    char hex_value = 0x5E; //94 in dec or ^ in char

    new_value = (char)(value1%hex_value); //300 % 94 = 18;

    new_value += bang; //18 + 33 = 51 in dec or the number 3 symbol in char;

    printf("dec_val: %d, char encoding: %c\n", (int)new_value, new_value);


}
```

Comment: nice, this definitiely clears up the issue regarding chars. Do you know of any way that I could provoke this binary to enter the conditional that I show at the top of my question? eventhough I cannot predict the value of `__s2`